# Modify variable string

Tags: php, string

Quick question,

I have the following string which is a coma separated list of tags:

```
$tagcap = "tag1, tag2, tag3";
```

How do I go about obtaining a single string that looks like this:

```
$string = "#tag1, #tag2, #tag3;
```

In other words, simply adding # in front of each word?

Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks a lot, that seems perfect except it also adds a # infront of words with hyphens, for example: self-shot becomes #self-#shot, how can I fix this?

Edit 2: Thanks for fast help guys, issue fixed!

Comment: if that was really your string, str_replace(), but i bet its not. and you want help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tagcap = "tag1, tag2, self-shot";
echo preg_replace( "/([a-z0-9-_]+)/i", "#$1", $tagcap );
```

Which outputs:

```
#tag1, #tag2, #self-shot
```

This prefixes any series of letters, numbers, dashes (-), or underscores with a hash (#).

Demo: http://codepad.org/0WgaZg2L

Comment: I kept this tab open to accept it today, it hadn't been long enough last night and I had to head to bed ;) Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '#$1', $str);
```

**Update:**

To include `-` char, use

```
$str = preg_replace('/([a-z0-9-]+)/i', '#$1', $str);
```

Where `([a-z0-9]+)` will match with any letter, number, and `-` chars. The `i` flag will make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems perfect except it also adds a # infront of words with hyphens, for example: self-shot becomes #self-#shot, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Sherif Please update your question to list the various types of formats you'll be accomodating.

Comment: that's what happens when you use an "example" use the real values or don't bother asking

Comment: I used an example because the string is made of variables, I was lucky to find this issue with the one I tested. No need to be rude @dagon

Comment: @Sherif sorry for the typho. See JonathanSampon's answer instead. I wanted to type the regex like his answer but I missed some chars :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$tagcap = "tag1, tag2, tag3";

$tagcap = str_replace("t","#t",$tagcap );
echo $tagcap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this, but this is other alternate using php functions.

```
<?php
$tagcap = "tag1, tag2, tag3";
$res = explode(',',$tagcap);
$values = array();
foreach($res as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($value)){
  $values[] = '#'.$value;
}

$finalResult = implode('',$values);
echo $finalResult;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution without Regex:

```
$string = "tag1,tag2,tag3";
function addPrefix(&$item,$key,$prefix)
{
   $item = $prefix.$item;
}

$arr = explode(",",$string);
array_walk($arr,"addPrefix","#");
echo implode($arr,","); //output "#tag1,#tag2,#tag3"
```